# How to make Google Maps remember my language?

Tags: google-maps, localization

Although this is minor issue, it is annoying. 
I'm usually logged into my Google Account and my Chrome browser remembers my login. All other Google services remember my chosen language. Only Google Maps, although it remembers my location, it does not remember my preferred language. Instead it displays language of my location.

Another annoying thing is, that if I navigate away from there, it keeps the language.

The trick is to put `?hl=<culture code>`, eg. `?hl=pl-PL` at the end of URL. Then it already displays in my chosen language (Polish).

Is there any other place, where I can "tell" Maps what language I want to use? I already have my language in Google preferences, and it works for other things (like search, GMail, G+, etc.).

Comment: Try changing your browser’s language also.

Comment: My browser also uses my preferred language. Only thing is, I have my location set (which is abroad).

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes, you can change the language in the 3-horizontal-bars menu on the left of the "Search Google Maps" section.  Open the menu, look down just below More Info,.. and click Language.

Personally I changed it many times to English, restarting afterwards, etc.. still it reverts back to German for every new tab of Google Maps. I figure Google will fix it eventually.